# Esper in-memory table alteration in runtime

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I have created an in-memory table in Esper engine and inserted some data. Now, I have to alter this table, add a new column, but couldn't find anything about the alteration of tables in Esper documentation, is there any other way to alter the table?

BTW, I am using EsperHA.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the window like this:

```
create window ABC ... as ABCType
```

... you can modify ABCType at runtime. There are update methods for event types in the runtime config APIs. When ABYType is a bean reloading the class does it too.